# How do I turn off auto-repeat temporarily using java KeyStroke

Tags: java, keyboard

I have a java application that allows the user to define a keystroke to do a particular action. One of the actions is to read microphone input while the key is pressed, stopping when it is released.  So I defined 2 actions, one for key down and one for key up.  When the user keys down, I get multiple key down actions corresponding to the auto-repeat function of the keyboard.  I implemented a clumsy `repeat` flag as in below which works most of the time (I occasionally don't get the key up action, which leaves it in a bad state). 
**My question:** Is there a way to disable the repeat temporarily?   Or a more clever (robust) way to handle the repeated keystrokes?

```
private static boolean repeat = false;
private void setupHotKey(MyKeyStroke key, MacroAction action)
    {
        JComponent panel = ((MyComponent)(rootPane.getContentPane())).getSwingComponent();
        InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(key.getKeyStroke(false), action.getName() + "DOWN");
        inputMap.put(key.getKeyStroke(true), action.getName() + "UP");
        panel.getActionMap().put(action.getName() + "DOWN", new AbstractAction(action.getName())
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    LOGGER.debug("Started " + action.getName() + " Repeat=" + repeat);
                    if (!repeat)  //Kind of ugly
                    {
                        repeat = true;
                        action.start();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        panel.getActionMap().put(action.getName() + "UP", new AbstractAction(action.getName())
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    action.stop();
                    repeat = false;
                    LOGGER.debug("Stopped " + action.getName() + " YAY!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Key repeat is an OS thing -- there's no way you can control it via Java (short of some API hook that you can interface with using JNI). You should think about having one key control recording and a different key controlling stop or having a key work as a toggle: press once to start recording, press again to stop. These are not inelegant solutions, and are potentially less annoying to the user.

Comment: Thanks but holding a key down for talking is natural for my users, just like holding the PTT button on a walkie-talkie.  I realize that you can turn off key repeat in the OS, but that seems a bit too intrusive since the user will also be entering text and using their PC for other apps.  I am just fishing for better solution than what I came up with.  I was hoping for something I could do with the KeyStroke object or its peers to throw away the repeats.